# JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest() issues

Tags: javascript, filereader

I've been looking through a lot of previously asked questions and I'm still stumped on how to get this fileReader to work. Currently the code I have is as follows:

```
var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
function updateWineProfile(name){
  //write bio info 
  var filePath = "Data/"+name+".txt"; 
  loadFile(filePath, name);   
} 
function loadFile(filePath, wineName) { 
  reader.onreadystatechange = displayContents(wineName); 
  reader.onload = doneLoading(wineName); 
  reader.open('get', filePath, true); 
  reader.send(); 
}
function displayContents(wineName) { 
  if(reader.readyState === 4 && reader.status === 200) { 
        reader.responseText = formatText(reader.responseText, wineName); 
        //document.getElementById('Info').innerHTML = ""; 
  } else{
        reader.responseText = formatText(reader.responseText, wineName); 
        document.getElementById('Info').innerHTML = formatText("Text Loading.   Please Try Again.", wineName); 
  } 
}
 function doneLoading(name) {
   document.getElementById('Info').innerHTML = formatText(this.responseText, name); 
}
```

I have a list of names, and for each name I have a .txt file with "Info". `updateWineProfile` is called during an onClick event handler on the list of names.

My issue is that it only works after the second click. Imagine I have a list of 'A' and 'B'. If I click 'A' for the first time it'll read my little "Text Loading" line. But once I click 'B' it populates the `'Info'` with item A's bio while displaying item B's name.

It seems that `this.responseText` isn't updated when its passed into `formatText()`. I thought that adding the `reader.onload` would fix this, but it hasn't.

(I'm only reading local files)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a function to `onload` and `onreadystatechange`.

You are calling `displayContents(wineName)` and `doneLoading(wineName)` **immediately** and then assigning their return values  (`undefined` in both cases as they have no `return` statements).